# How do I convert datetime to this format `WEEKDAY, DAY MONTH YEAR`

Tags: ruby

How do I convert datetime object to this format `Thu, 02 July 2015`

That is `WEEKDAY, DAY MONTH YEAR`

Comment: You don't "convert" a date time object.  You *display* it's value.  Display it with a particular format, with respect to a particular time zone.  The DateTime method is `strftime( format )`: https://hackhands.com/format-datetime-ruby/

Comment: sorry for my poor concept

Comment: I expect you will select @Arup's answer, because it's the most direct approach, and also because it's likely to be the only answer. (The alternative is to pull out each piece of the string and join them, which is clunky and unnecessary.) Even so, I suggest you hold off selecting his (or another) answer for awhile.  This is my advice for any question you might post.  There's no rush, and there are at least two reasons to wait: 1) you don't want to discourage other (possibly better) answers; and 2) it's discourteous (imo) to select an answer while some  readers are still preparing theirs.

Comment: @paulsm4 You convert date time to a string. Then, you display it. `strftime` creates a new instance of a string.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the format string:

```
require 'date'

DateTime.now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y")
# => "Wed, 10 Jun 2015"
DateTime.now.strftime("%a, %d %B %Y")
# => "Wed, 10 June 2015"
```

Comment: @Arup : I suggest add one more option `("%a, %d %B %Y")` for full month as OP has mention in expected output full month `July` instead `Jul`